# Is there a slang word or idiom for someone who borrows money from friends or relatives and never (or rarely) pays them back?

Tags: slang, idiom-requests, epithet-requests

Edit - My question doesn't refer to bank loans or credit card accounts.  **Nor does it refer to getting things out of other people's generosity. It is specifically about money and the putative duplicate doesn't address that.** If there is no specific word for someone who never pays back his debts, then the answer here should be "there is no specific word for that".

I'm looking for a slang word or idiom for a person who borrows small amounts from friends or relatives (say US$ 50-200) and never pays them back. Usually this kind of person has low-income or is jobless. He is irresponsible, he knows he won't be able to pay his debts but doesn't care. (Perhaps because he knows nobody will be taking him to court because of US$20 or 50.)

> **"I wouldn't lend him one cent. Everybody knows he's a ........."**

Comment: @ermanen I've gone through the link you mentioned and there isn't an answer there.  My question here is about Money and has nothing to do with generosity. So much so that this kind of person becomes a notorious non-payer and will eventually find it difficult to borrow more.

Comment: @ermanen Yes, answers are the same but none of them seems to address the specificity of the question, they fit there but not here. I'm sure there is a slang word for this, but it hasn't come up so far. I admit, however, that you may be right and I may be wrong. But I try hard not to formulate a useless question. :)

Comment: How about [welch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/welch) or welcher? Though it is usually used in betting/gambling.

Comment: That's the closest I've seen so far.

Comment: Ok I will add that an answer and retract my close vote but maybe you can add more details about why moocher, leech, sponge, scrounger etc. do not fit.

Comment: I have a friend like that, so we call him Crime- as in Crime doesn't pay :)

Comment: Perhaps the choice of the best word will also depend on whether the person is merely incapable of managing their money well (and has generous friends), or is intentionally taking advantage of other people's generosity. A lot of these terms convey the latter meaning.

Comment: @TomFenech Usually this kind of person has low-income or is jobless. He is irresponsible, he knows he won't be able to pay his debts but doesn't worry about it. (Perhaps because he knows nobody will be taking him to court because of US$ 50.) I will add it to the question.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. OP showed an effort and updated the question to explain why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: As you can see, there are a lot of them. Pejorative terms are never hard to find. Humans have many uses for them, and often deploy great creativity and specificity with regard to the varieties of pejoration.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would you consider pejorative a term that describes exactly someone's character?   For instance, "someone who borrows money and never pays back"  Don't they deserve whatever term is coined for them?  And, once they deserve it, is it still considered pejorative?  This is not a rhetorical question.  I'd really appreciate to hear what you have to say about it.

Comment: @Centaurus: Who said anything about "deserve"? Oral is not the same as moral. Pejoration can be anything, whether brutal and offensive or nuanced and ironic, that calls unpleasant attention to someone; 'unpleasant', that is, in the opinion of the victim. I don't apply the term to non-humans; cars, flies, and politicians have no shame and can't be offended by pejoration).

Comment: Not so very many years ago, people would have understood the comparison "he's like Wimpy trying to raise money for a hamburger." In countless Popeye cartoons, the sleepy-looking, mustachioed (and voracious) character Wimpy exercised his catch-phrase "I will gladly pay you Tuesday for a hamburger today." Somehow, in all those cartoons, Tuesday never came.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can consider ***welch*** or ***welcher***. These terms are used for people who fail to repay a small debt. The debt is usually a betting or gambling debt but these terms can be applied to other contexts as well. They are considered derogatory.

> welch (n)
>
> A person who defaults on an obligation, especially a small one.
>
> *She's a welch. That isn't hers, I lent her that watering can three years ago.*
>
> welch (v)
>
> 1. To fail to repay a small debt.
> 2. To fail to fulfill an obligation.
>
> http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/welch

---

Related questions:

- [Are the terms "welsh" or "welch" (as in reneging on a bet) derogatory toward the Welsh people?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72806/are-the-terms-welsh-or-welch-as-in-reneging-on-a-bet-derogatory-toward-the)
- [What would you call someone who imposes on other people's generosity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94724/what-would-you-call-someone-who-imposes-on-other-peoples-generosity/95101#95101)
- [What do you call someone who is always asking for favours?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172162/what-do-you-call-someone-who-is-always-asking-for-favours)

Comment: Perfect. This is the only answer which exactly matches the semantics of the question, I think. The rest more generally describe someone who is cheap, without any specific implication of failure to repay small debts.

Comment: 'welching' refers to a specific act--failing to pay a debt. The question here goes to the manner of extracting the money from acquaintances. The question asks for a word or idiom describing a chronic pattern of behavior.

Comment: @user3847: You asked for a noun. Welch and welcher are used as a noun for someone that doesn't pay a small debt. It could be that they borrowed money as well. I gave this answer because you said other answers do not fit, yet you chose the answer that you thought it does not fit before.

Comment: you're right. I read so many comments and answers to other questions this morning that I got confused.

Comment: Despite my numeric lead, I'm inclined to agree that welching is a slightly better word than mooching. Mooching might be money, but more likely means begging half your lunch sandwich or a beer from your fridge. Welching is far more moolah-oriented, albeit it can be large sum. Welching is a far more serious crime than mooching. Both terms, of course are a bit quaint, more likely to be heard on the Honeymooners than Big Brother.

Comment: bear in mind the first of the related questions, using this term might get you in trouble, probably more so in the UK

Comment: Good one!   I couldn't think of this at all, but knew it was right as soon as I laid eyes on it!

Comment: Hmm. For me at least _welch/welcher_ is limited specifically to gambling. The idea of not lending somebody money because he's a welcher doesn't make sense to me. I agree that "moocher" can involve things other than money, but usually it doesn't.

Comment: I've only heard "welch" used in the context of "welch on a bet".

Comment: I think "welch" is more commonly used as a verb.

Answer (score 66):

**Moocher**--a bit old-fashioned and not much in use nowadays.

**Deadbeat** is a bit more general.

Or **sponge**.

Comment: Mooch/moocher is good, as in "Joe's a no good moocher", or "Joe makes me sick, he's always mooching off his grandparents".

Comment: There's also just Mooch. There's also [Minnie the moocher.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ5gCGJorKk)

Comment: I use *mooch* regularly, so I wouldn't consider it old-fashioned. However, the question specifically mentions that "borrowing without repaying" is a key factor. I believe *mooch*, *moocher*, and the other terms in this answer are more applicable to people in a group who rely unnecessarily heavily on the other people in the group, themselves contributing far less than they're able. For example, if my brother lives with me in hard times, I don't expect him to back-pay rent when he gets back on his feet, but if he never does anything within his means to help around the house then he's mooching.

Comment: "Deadbeat" is much more on-target than "moocher."

Answer (score 21):

**Deadbeat** specifically means someone who doesn't pay back money borrowed, or debts owed, *ever*. A deadbeat borrows, and betrays trust of family and friends.

A *moocher* or a *sponge* or a *freeloader* or a *scrounger* have similar meanings to each other, but different than deadbeat. All are cheapskates, consistently taking advantage of the generosity or obliviousness of others in a non-business context. These terms do not necessarily, or even customarily, refer to taking money, but rather, sharing a ride but not reciprocating as promised, sharing a hotel room at a convention but not contributing to the expenses etc.

It isn't especially relevant to this question, but since a highly regarded community member with an up voted answer used an **ngram** (not "ngam"), I will do similarly to make my case for **deadbeat**.

[image: google ngram word frequency chart]

See **[Deadbeat versus moocher, sponge, scrounger and freeloader](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scrounger%2Cmoocher%2Cfreeloader%2Csponger%2Cdeadbeat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscrounger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoocher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfreeloader%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csponger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeadbeat%3B%2Cc0)** for the associated Google Ngram Viewer query.

Comment: I was going to upvote your answer, but then I saw it's a duplicate. Please see @Jens Andersen's.

Comment: I usually hear "deadbeat" in the context of a father who refuses to pay child support. That may be sufficient to explain the uptick in the ngram- I would be interested to see the curve if you searched for the specific term "deadbeat dad". Incidentally in the years since 2000 the frequency of "deadbeat" has started to drop...

Comment: @Floris: That's a relatively recent, specific use (and with a lot of popularity). But the *general* term is exactly applicable here. Of course, this is English, in 20 years "deadbeat" may be so associated with "deadbeat dad" that the older general meaning fades away. Don't think we're close to that yet, though.

Comment: This meaning of deadbeat is limited to North America (google definition).   I looked it up because I couldn't beleive it.  Over here, a deadbeat is "an idle, feckless, or disreputable person." (google).

Comment: @GreenAsJade The OP didn't specify usage by region using the tags intended for such. If so, and anything other than North American English were requested, then your point may well be valid, though "over here" is UK? Au/NZ? I'm curious, not being difficult ;O)

Comment: While "welch" is also a good answer, this is the one that I'd put in the OP's blank most naturally, so I think this is the best one.

Comment: Thank you much, @Casey after all this time. It always great to be validated!

Answer (score 18):

A **scrounger** is a term commonly used for this kind of person:

[to scrounge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scrounge): (from TFD)

> - To obtain (something) by begging or borrowing with no intention of reparation: scrounged a few dollars off my brother.

[to scrounge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scrounge): (from OED)

> - Seek to obtain (something, typically food or money) at the expense or through the generosity of others or by stealth. ( from OED).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scrounger%2Cmoocher%2Cfreeloader%2Csponger&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscrounger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoocher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfreeloader%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csponger%3B%2Cc0): scrounger, freeloader, sponger and moocher.

Comment: To me, scrounger just means someone who looks for things that are available for free and doesn't imply that they obtain them dishonestly or with any (unfulfilled) promise to pay someone for them. For example, "I scrounged an old tv set my neighbor was going to throw away."

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question and is just wrong.

Comment: Scrounge  fits the context as explained clearly  in the definitions I posted!!

Comment: @Josh61 - It doesn't.  Not even a little bit.  Worse is that it is confusing to a non-native speaker.  What's worse is that you Ngram words that do work and compare them to a word whose definition is well off from what was wanted.

Answer (score 11):

Sponger: Freeloader: Parasite: Leech: Bloodsucker; will all serve your purpose, but use at your own discretion as some are stronger than others. Sponger could be used quite lightly, but parasite would be harsh.

Example:

'You sir! Are a freeloading, bloodsucking parasite!'

Comment: A freeloader might just crash on your couch and eat everything in your fridge but never ask for money. A *sponge* or *sponger* is specifically a money borrower who doesn't repay though.

Comment: I would say the use of parasite has more of a social meaning, like the guy who's always on unemployment. Same with leech.

Comment: A freeloader might just crash on your couch and eat everything in your fridge and ask you for 10 bucks in the morning

Answer (score 9):

In New Zealand and Australia we might use the term [*bludger*](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=define%3A%20bludger&oq=define%3A%20bludger&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3239j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Another similar Australian slang word is [*scab*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=scab&defid=624190).

Answer (score 8):

I hear "mooch" more than I hear "moocher." To me it means someone who's always looking to get other people to give them stuff.

I don't know that I've heard "scrounger" or "scrounge" since I was a teen -- which is a long time ago.

To me, "deadbeat" is the closest word, as in "deadbeat dad," a father who owes child support but isn't paying it.

As with most slang, though, it's subjective and probably regional.

Comment: Deadbeat is by far the most direct word for this.

Comment: I had only ever heard "scrounger" used in a Monty Python skit ("He says the bird are scrounging!"). I had to look it up. I assumed it was a British thing.

Comment: I almost never use deadbeat in this way. To me a deadbeat dad is one that welches on his fatherly duties; more than financial.

Comment: @fredsbend: That's *a* use of deadbeat, certainly, but someone who fails to repay loans is absolutely a deadbeat as well.

Comment: I'm with "Deadbeat". It carries the correct connotation here. Someone who CAN pay but chooses not to.

Answer (score 7):

In the digital generation, **leecher** is also used. It can include other kinds of social parasitism, but the not-repaying-money scenario is a very good example for it.

As far as I'm aware, the origin is from P2P networks. But maybe there is an earlier use which was already established when the term became common in P2P.

Comment: [*Figuratively applied to human parasites since 1784*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leech): I don't think this has its origin in P2P networks.

Comment: @Geobits what you linked is "leech", as in the animal. Not "leecher", which is a different word, the opposite of "seeder". I can imagine it being derived from the animal, but it's still not the same.

Comment: I would say it's just a variant on *leech*. The figurative meaning is the same.

Comment: I disagree with the variant interpretation. "Leech" and "leecher" are two different words, and in their original context, none can be substituted for the other. Each of them creates completely different associations in the one who hears them (at least if the person has heard "leecher" before in a network context). It is like the Italian-italic case discussed recently: one came from the other, but the meaning has deviated a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Another synonym I haven't seen mentioned yet is *cadger*.  To [*cadge*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cadge) is to persuade someone to give you something, and a *cadger* is someone who cadges things.

*Cadger* should not be confused with *codger*, which is a mildly derogatory term for an old man.

Answer (score 5):

'schnorrer'--A Yiddish/German term

> to describe a freeloader who frequently asks for little things, like cigarettes or small sums of money without offering a return. The English usage of the word denotes a sly chiseler who will get money out of his acquaintances any way he can, often through an air of entitlement. A *schnorrer* is distinguished from an ordinary beggar by dint of his boundless 'chutzpah' [offensive nerve]. Like 'moocher', 'schnorrer' does not apply to direct begging or destitution, but rather to a habit of getting things (foods, tools) by politely or insistently borrowing them with no intention of return. [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorrer)]

Comment: Perhaps you could show more clearly what parts of above are quoted, and provide a link.  For quoted stuff put a > at beginning of line

Comment: @jwpat: The poster's wording was only slightly different from the original quotation from Wikipedia, so I restored the original and formatted it as a block quote. I hope that user3847 will feel free to add further distinctions and clarifications outside the block quote, if any such seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In my circle if a friend borrowed money from another he would be called a **reneger**.  Actually there is nothing in the world worse than a reneger.

> A person who reneges.
>
> To welsh on bets.
>
> To consistently not honor contracts or commitments. I never make bets
>   with Jack. He's a reneger and won't pay when he loses, but has no
>   problem collecting when he wins.

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not qualify as a slang, one humorous term that I have used to refer to a friend of mine is '**black-hole**' in reference to the characteristic of this astronomical element which keeps sucking everything which comes near it and nothing ever comes out of it :)

Answer (score -3):

Intended for people who ask for small loans with inconsiderable ability to pay back obligations.

**loan shark**: someone who never pays back.
**loan junkie**: someone who constantly asks for a loan.

Comment: LOAN SHARK is NOT someone who is hungry for loans. he/she is someone who lends money at high rates of interest, more like a moneymaker.

Comment: 659 hits on Google say "**loan junkie**" is a thing. +1