# Word/phrase to describe a person who always searches to benefit from other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a formal word/phrase that describes a person who always searches to benefit from other people?

It is hard to recall the word in my own language to translate. So I decided to give it a try and ask here.

I prefer adjective

Comment: Does this suggest "parasite" or "leech"?  It seems as though in English we often express unpleasant concepts through metaphor.

Comment: @Rob_Ster I want the formal one, sorry.

Comment: Do you care if the word/phrase is a noun or an adjective?

Comment: "Opportunist" (adj., "opportunistic") has the flavor of one who actively seeks and takes advantage of others.  I will stand by "parasite" in formal speech, while admitting that "leech" is pejoratively informal.

Comment: A people user? Not really formal, but it is neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you may be in search of the common word "[freeloader](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGGE___US550US551&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=811&q=define%20freeloader&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjhsLKw0drKAhXKu4MKHU1MArEQ_SoIIzAA)", "a person who takes advantage of others' generosity without giving anything in return." While it's informal, it is far more common than most other applicable terms. A [synonym of beggar](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/beggar?s=t) might suit your needs though, perhaps [mendicant](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mendicant) (more formal and doubles as an adjective, but less commonly understood), [panhandler](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=panhandler) (informal), etc.

The fact is that if one fits this description, he can't be too picky about what people call him.

**Google Definitions**

[Freeloader](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGGE___US550US551&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=811&q=define%20freeloader&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjhsLKw0drKAhXKu4MKHU1MArEQ_SoIIzAA): "a person who takes advantage of others' generosity without giving anything in return."

[Beggar](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGGE___US550US551&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=811&q=define%20freeloader&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjhsLKw0drKAhXKu4MKHU1MArEQ_SoIIzAA#q=define%20beggar):(1st sense) "a person, typically a homeless one, who lives by asking for money or food."

[Mendicant](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mendicant): *adjective* - "Given to begging" *noun* - "Beggar"

**Wikipedia Definition**

[Panhandling](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj2toGpvN_KAhXKWhoKHTWoCDAQFggmMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBegging&usg=AFQjCNGa_NhEvJrS-dIfEZ5pqTQieWOnRw&sig2=Nd8jKK0pQzTOpLDGLUDd_A&bvm=bv.113370389,d.d2s): "Begging or panhandling is the practice of imploring others to grant a favor, often a gift of money, with little or no expectation of reciprocation. Beggars may be found in public places such as transport routes, urban parks, and near busy markets."

Answer (score 2):

**Parasite** (*parasitic* for the adjective). In a generic biological context, [parasitism is "non-mutual symbiotic relationship between species"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitism). I like the euphemism in "non-mutual symbiotic".

You can find many additional options and derivatives in SE.english question: [Is there a slang word or idiom for someone who borrows money from friends or relatives and never (or rarely) pays them back?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198615/is-there-a-slang-word-or-idiom-for-someone-who-borrows-money-from-friends-or-rel)

Answer (score 0):

'Scrounger' would be a suitable word for you.